# StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex Using HijriDatePicker?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I am using a many instances of Hijri Gerogian Datapicker, with gridview control, when I delete from the gridview I receive the following error:

```
StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex

Line 173:                    //to manage multiple instances of user control postback, incase the postback happend due to culture changeed in current control,
Line 174:                    //the other user contrls culture drop down list to be changed accordingly. Also year and month dropdown lists according to culture 
Line 175:                    if (strPostBackControlName != "" && strPostBackControlName.Substring(strPostBackControlName.LastIndexOf("$")) == "$ddlLocaleChoice")
Line 176:                    {
Line 177:                        if (ddlLocaleChoice.SelectedValue == arabicCulture.Name)


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex]
   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) +13011515
   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex) +15
   Hijri_Greg_DatePicker_Sample.HijriGregDatePicker.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Mawni\Desktop\Hijri_Greg_DatePicker_Sample\HijriGregDatePicker.ascx.cs:175
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this fragment of code:

```
strPostBackControlName.LastIndexOf("$")
```

It will return last index of `$` in string, but when `$` is not found it will return `-1` as result. Later you will try to call `strPostBackControlName.Substring` with this result, but `Substring` has following prototype:

```
public string Substring (int startIndex);
```

You can't call it with start index less then 0, of course (because indexes in string start from `0`). Add check that `LastIndexOf("$")` isn't `-1` or make sure that `strPostBackControlName` always contains `$` in it.